# crystal report Header row merge with sub items possible?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report in which I group items by salesman as shown below:

`Sam`

```
item11  $22 OK
itemt2  $3  return
item3   $11 OK
```

`Saneesh`

```
item15  $212    OK
itemt12 $13 OK
item3   $11 OK
```

But I need display report as shown below:

```
Sam        item11 $22    OK

           itemt2 $3   return

           item3  $11  OK


Saneesh    item15   $212 OK

           itemt12  $13 OK

           item3    $11 OK
```

...ie. the group header shows on the first sub row of items and it is not repeating.  Is this possible in crystal reports? Sam shows on the first row of items (item11) and Saneesh shows next to item15.
PLZ help

Answer (score 0):

You can put the group header name inside the detail section and then from the format dialog box for that header name select the option "Suppress Duplicates", this will prevent the repeating of the salesman name. And also you may need to suppress the group header section so that the blank section can be avoided

Say you have only one group in your report, so structure will be as follows

```
Group Header 1     
  Details         SAM     item11  $22   OK                   
                          itemt2  $3    return                   
                          item3   $11   OK  
                  Saneesh item15  $212  OK                   
                          itemt12 $13   OK                   
                          item3   $11   OK  
Group Footer 1
```